# What would happen if you dropped a stick of dynamite from a high place?

Tags: physical-chemistry, explosions

If you were to drop a stick of dynamite from a high place, what would happen once it hit the ground, and why?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. At what point is the stick of dynamite ignited?

Comment: @BobD It wouldn't be. Apparently it won't explode if it's not ignited, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamite is nitroglycerine rendered insensitive by mixing it with diatomaceous earth. By design it will not explode upon impact but requires a powerful explosive shock from a *blasting cap* in order to set it off.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly true. If dynamite has be stored for a long time it is possible that
a) the dynamite stick can "sweat" and the "sweat is nitro".
b) nitro can sometimes crystalize like sugar on the ends of a stick of dynamite, and those "crystals"  could explode on impact with a hard surface.

However is dynamite sticks are stored properly, some experts say that the sticks could be gently rotated so as to prevent crystals from forming on the ends of the sticks.

Comment: The way you've written this, it sounds like a response to the other answer to this question rather than a standalone answer, but there's most of an answer here. It would be better if you reworded it in a way that it's a full response to the question even if the other answer were not there.